# How to align widget's child position according to touch coordinats regards this widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of Cards widget, and I want some child appear when user touches this exact card, and align it accordingly to touch point coordinates, e.g. centerRight, topRight, bottomRight.

How can I achieve this?
Here's some pseudocode to illustrate my question.

```
        var position = Alignment.bottomRight;

        InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            /// get touch point regards first container
            /// if touched in 1/3 of child's height, then position == Alignment.topRight, and so on
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 100, width: 100,
            child: Container(
              alignment: position,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: @emivaized as your question is on UI, why don't you help us understand your problem with a snapshot or a mock picture? What you have, and what you want to accomplish. Also it could be helpful to know at which point you stop, where is your blocker

Comment: @Alessio Okay, let me explain better -- I have a Dismissible widget with height, that exceeds visible screen, so I want Icon in Dismissible's background being displayed accordingly to which part of widget is currently visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and modify as your requirement !

```
Alignment position = Alignment.center;
  double w = 0, h = 0, currentX = 0, currentY = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    w = context.size.width;
    h = context.size.height;

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          alignment: position,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTapUp: (det) {
              print(det.localPosition);
              setState(() {
                currentX = det.localPosition.dx;
                currentY = det.localPosition.dy;
                if (currentX <= (w / 2) && currentY <= (h / 2))
                  position = Alignment.topLeft;
                else if (currentX < (w / 2) && currentY > (h / 2))
                  position = Alignment.bottomLeft;
                else if (currentX > (w / 2) && currentY <= (h / 2))
                  position = Alignment.topRight;
                else if (currentX > (w / 2) && currentY > (h / 2))
                  position = Alignment.bottomRight;
                //and so on... centerLeft,centerRight, etc..
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 150,
              height: 150,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: In this code touch coordinates are being compared to whole display size (which is get from MediaQuery.of(context).size here). But how to compare them to parent widget size? Like I want to know, when first and second vertical halfs of Container() were touched.

Comment: Replace h and w with your custom sized container's measurements !

Comment: Seems you don't quite understand my problem. I have a list of Cards, and want to get touch coordinates in comparison to touched Card's constraints -- not in comparison to whole screen size.

Comment: Okay, I solved my problem by replacing 'MediaQuery.of(context).size' with 'context.size.height'. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure! Please also update your answer to add this important information: " should replace 'MediaQuery.of(context).size' with 'context.size.height' ", and I will accept as the correct one